# DropDownList : Style the Unselected Choice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, styling

We're using the Html.DropDownList and other controls in various MVC3 user data entry forms.

When a user is editing a records data values and they haven't specified values for a DropDownList then the optionLabel text of 'Select One' is displayed in the input field.

We'd like to make it more obvious to the end-user when they're viewing a screen of data that 'Select One' isn't a data value by showing it in a different font colour (blue ?) and in italics.

Has anyone any ideas how to simply achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the DropDownList is required... just mark that field as requiered using the somehow standard red "(*)".  If the user submit the form, the client side validation will display the message telling the user that this field is required.

Answer (score 0):

The level of customization of the `<select>` HTML element is pretty limited. IIRC you could change the color but I am not sure that you can show it in italics:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Foo, 
    Model.Foos, 
    "-- select a foo --", 
    new { @class = "foo" }
)
```

and then in your CSS file define the `.foo` rule:

```
.foo option:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want more customizations of the look and feel of the standard `<select>` element you might take a look at some of the [available jQuery plugins](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=css+select+custom+jquery+plugin&oq=css+select+custom+jquery+plugin&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...59789l62610l4l62825l20l20l0l0l0l0l168l1953l14j6l20l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=41acde84586da885&biw=1440&bih=795).